# How to pass Data from express to script tag after submit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a View called "historicos.ejs". In the 1st load, the page only has 2 date pickers to make a range query, submit button and chart(google charts) in blank. I need to make the query and pass the data after the 2nd render(after pressing submit) into the chart.

This is the script tag placed in the head of my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // his with query data from the server
    var histo = his;
    console.log(histo)  
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('datetime', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatura (C)');

      data.addRows();

      var options = {
        width: 550,
        height: 363,
        title: 'Comportamiento de la Temperatura',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Tiempo desde '
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Temperatura'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tem_line'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

The `console.log()` command in the second line show an empty array or undefined in the browser console.

This is the "historicos.ejs" controller

```
app.get('/historicos', function(req, res) {
res.render("historicos.ejs")  
});

app.post('/historicos/buscar', function(req, res) {
//...some query.... query return "his" variable with the data
res.render("historicos.ejs", {
  his:JSON.stringity(his)
   }) 
});
```

NOTE: I tested my code without the stringify and showed it in the view with ejs `<% %>` and it works perfectly.

When I press the submit button, the console.log in the script does not show anything even if the data has the stringify data.

NOTE2: I tried `res.json(JSON.stringify(his)` and it works perfectly, it shows in the browser all the data from mongodb.

So my question is, what can I do to pass the variable into my script to plot the data into the chart?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to wrap the json in a script tag with type application/json.  This will prevent the script from actually running and allow you to use the DOM to query the text content and parse it.

```html
<script id="histo-data" type="application/json">
    <%= his %>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = document.getElementById('histo-data').textContent.trim()
    if(data){
        var histo = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(histo)  
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']})
        // ...
```

Here's a quick demo showing this works for some static JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/grnp8n9n/

Comment: var histo = JSON.parse(document.getElementById.textContent); ,what is textcontent?, you mean histo-data ?

Comment: I hit submit too soon.  It's edited.  We get the histo-data script node and then grab the `textContent` which is the JSON string.  `textContent` is similar to the non-standard `innerText`. More here if you're interested: http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: It looks like both your get and post routes are using the same template, but only the post is passing the his variable to the template.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: I thought so, but It is a requirement to show the chart int he same template. I used a if statement to solve the "his" error and now i got this in the browser console.  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 3 column 2 of the JSON data buscar:14:18

Comment: I'm thinking that's because if `his` is undefined the `#histo-data` only contains whitespace.  What are you expecting to happen on that get route with regards to the chart?

Comment: As I said, the initial request it only shows two date pickers, after I press the find button the page will reload with the post method and will bring to the view "his" with the needed data and I need that data into a chart

Comment: Okay.  So since you don't want to display the chart until there is data, you can check that there is data before initializing the chart.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.  Another option would be to use ejs to wrap the entire block in an if statement so none of the initialization code for the chart would be sent unless there was data to display.

Comment: I still have to stringify the "his" in the server?. I am using an if to manage erros related if the his variable is present or not